# Uri null error in Kotlin, Android Studio : java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: {null}

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating an app in Android Studio with Jetpack Compose. In a main screen, I have a button, that when it is clicked, it opens the gallery through `registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia())`, then when the image is picked,  it navigates to another screen where the image is displayed, and then analysed with MlKit vision. This is the mainActivity

```
private val selectMedia = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()){ uri ->
        if (uri != null){
            val encodedUri = Uri.encode(
                uri
                    .toString()
                    .replace('%', '|')
            )
        }
    }


    @ExperimentalPermissionsApi
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @ExperimentalCoilApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            AppNavigation(navController = navController, selectMedia, encodedUri)
        }
```

This is the main Screen and when the button is clicked the gallery launches, and with a LaunchedEffect I navigate to another screen

```
ox(
                        Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .clickable {
                                selectMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
                            }, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                            val gallery =
                                painterResource(id = R.drawable.icons8_im_genes_de_carpetas_32__1_)
                            Image(
                                painter = gallery,
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier.size(36.dp, 36.dp)
                            )
                            Text(text = "Imágenes", fontFamily = Inter, fontSize = 12.sp)
                        }
                    }
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = selectMedia){
                        navController.popBackStack()
                        navController.navigate(AppScreens.SecondScreenImage.route + "/{$encodedUri}")
                    }
```

This is the file where the uri is received

```
val imageUri = textUri?.toUri()

    val textChanged = mutableStateOf("")
    val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

    val image = InputImage.fromFilePath(context, imageUri!!)
    recognizer.process(image)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            textChanged.value = it.text
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("TEXT_REC", it.message.toString())
        }
```

I need to encode the Uri in order to send it through navController, but I think that the problem I am getting, is that the encodedUri constant is null or at least a null String, and when it reaches the final screen, and it is turned to Uri, it does not have content to transform, because the error I am getting appears i the last screen in the image constant.
What could I do? How can I access to the encodedUri constant when it is in MainActivity, and inside a constant it does not have scope?

Answer (score 0):

Main problem here is your `LaunchedEffect`. You are using `selectMedia` as a key - that's wrong. Launched effect runs the first time it is in composition and then whenever its keys change. In your case, the key never changes. What you have to do is to base your LaunchedEffect on the uri instead:

```
LaunchedEffect(encodedUri) {
    if (encodedUri != null) {
        // navigate
    }
}
```

In your activity, `encodedUri` has to be `State`, or some other kind of observable object:

```
var encodedUri by mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
```

---

If you don't need to define the launcher inside of the activity though, it would be better to move it completely to compose:

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    val selectMedia = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(),
    ){ uri ->
        // parse uri and navigate from here
        val encodedUri = ...
        navController.navigate(...)
    }

    Button(onClick = { selectMedia.launch(...) }) {}
}
```

Comment: I have implemented what you have told me, but now I get a nullPointerException. I have implemented null-safety measures i all the navigation process. But I think that the problem is that the value of encoded Uri does not update. Thanks for your attention, and what should I do?

Comment: Where do you get the NullPointerException? Check if the encodedUri is null where you call `navigate` - it shouldn't be. If you get the NullPointerException on the second screen when you call `val imageUri = textUri?.toUri()!!`, that's gonna be another problem with the navigation and you didn't provide code how you define your navigation, so hard to tell.

Comment: look at my answer @Eduardo  you need to assign the encodedUri state. check again!

Comment: Yes Mado I have checked your correction, but the problem is that I cannot assign a remember and mutableStateOf inside MinaActivity, as it is not a Composable. I ´ll try to create all inside the mainScreen instead of the MainActivity

Comment: You dont need a remember inside activity, just `mutableStateOf()` works - as I suggested in my answer - and that works outside of compose too. But yeah, you will be better of with pure compose way definitely.

Comment: Guys maybe the question I should formulate you is : How can I through the val SelectMedia (maybe not selecting it in the MainActivity) , encode the Uri when it is chosen in the gallery, and send it to another screen using navController? Thanks guys for helping me even if we do not get the answer